# Reload jquery JSON every 5 second

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to make an dynamic listview which is reloading for changes every 5 seconds. It loads perfectly first time on load but my setinterval is not working correctly. It goes of every 5 seconds but it doesnt update my menu even though changes has been made?

Here is what i got so far:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function (){
    var userid=1;
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    $.getJSON("http://mypage.com/playermenu.php?callback=?&userid="+userid,          
        function(data){
            var content = []
            $.each(data , function(i,val){

                content.push(val.list);

            });

            $("#games").html(content.join(""));
            $('#games').listview('refresh');

            $.mobile.loading('hide');

        });
});

setInterval(function(){ 
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    $.getJSON("http://mypage.com/playermenu.php?callback=?&userid="+userid,          
        function(data){
            var content = []
            $.each(data , function(i,val){

                content.push(val.list);

            });

            $("#games").html(content.join(""));
            $('#games').listview('refresh');

            $.mobile.loading('hide');

        }); 
}, 5000);
```

The $.mobile.loading('show'); starts after 5 seconds but doesn't get to the $.mobile.loading('hide');

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You should seriously think about refactoring your code

Comment: Are you getting any Consol Errors?  Have you tried console.log("test") after your 'show' going through each line to see which one (if any) is messing up?

Comment: You are repeating the identical block of code twice.  Put it into one function and call that function from as many places as you need to.  Less to maintain this way, and much less code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var user_id` is in a different scope that the timeout function.  Put the timeout inside the document ready block and problem solved.  Also, consider refactoring your code to avoid so much repetition and improve maintainability.  For example:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function () {
    var userid = 1,
        url = 'http://mypage.com/playermenu.php?callback=?&userid=' + userid,
        callback = function (data) {
            var content = [];
            $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                content.push(val.list);
            });
            $('#games').html(content.join('')).listview('refresh');
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
        },
        fetchData = function () {
            $.mobile.loading('show');
            $.getJSON(url, callback);
        };
    fetchData();
    setInterval(fetchData, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Oh yes... this did the job. Not sure what you meen about refactoring? Can you please explain.

Comment: By refactoring, we mean essentially what I did: eliminate all the repetition and condense it down to more maintainable chunks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your user_id variable might not be visible in the anonymous function in setInterval.